# How do I check when a Pojo's property is null, then the Pojo must null with Groovy

Tags: groovy

How can I check Person, then auto check age is null ?

```
def person = new Person(name:'Jack')
//when i check person, how can i direct check the person.age is null and return false
if(person){

}else{
    log.info "person is not exist"
} 

class Person{
    def name
    def age
}
```

Comment: if you think your own answer is correct, than this question might be wrong.  what your answer seems to suggest is, that you look for a way, if some pogo has any properties with a value of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should rather use the [Groovy truth](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth) thing in your case:

```
class Person{
  def name
  int age
  boolean asBoolean(){
    0 < age
  }
}

assert new Person( age:2 )
assert !new Person( age:0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [safe navigation operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_safe_navigation_operator):

```
if (person?.age) { //if either person or age is null 
                   //(or other falsy value like 0) it will be falsy
      //...
}
```

You can also just chain checks:

```
if(person && person.age){}
```

BTW: instanceof of  classes should start with lowercase, so you should write:

```
def person = new Person(name:'Jack')
```

Comment: It seems to be not feasible,
Because I have a lot of object must to check,
So I need some way to check all Pojos, instead of check a property of the Pojo,

Comment: such as
if(isNull(Person)){}

def isNull(Object o){
    Field field = o.getFields().get......
    if(!field){
        return null
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

It seems work......
can someone give me advice?

```
import groovy.util.logging.Log4j
import java.lang.reflect.Field
import org.junit.Test

@Log4j
class TestNull {

    @Test
    void testNotNull(){
        ObjectA a = new ObjectA(a : "AAA", b : "BBB", c : "CCC", d:"DDD")
        if(isNull(a)){
            log.info "a is not null"
        }else{
            log.info "a is null object"
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testIsNull(){
        ObjectA a = new ObjectA(a : "AAA", b : "BBB", c : "CCC")
        if(isNull(a)){
            log.info "a is not null"
        }else{
            log.info "a is null object"
        }
    }

    def isNull(Object obj){
        Boolean value = true
        obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields().each{ Field field ->
            field.setAccessible(true)

            // check field is customize or not 
            if(!field.isSynthetic()){
                if(!field.get(obj)){
                    log.info "${field}_${field.get(obj)}"
                    value = false
                    return value
                }
            }
        }
        return value
    }
}

class ObjectA {
    def a
    def b
    def c
    def d
}
```

Comment: i'd change that name to something like `hasNullProperties`; `each` with the return here is basically wrong.  it works here, but it does not short circuit the loop (return in `each` just skips to the next item). use `every` instead.  also be aware, that you have asked for `not null` - but you check for groovy truth here.  this will also fail, if your property holds a `0` or `false` or `""`...